# Android admobs using google play services sdk not showing ads

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I am trying to integrate admob to my android app using new google play services sdk. But ads are not visible. It showing warning in log cat that > **Not enough space to show ad. Needs 480X75 pixels, but only has 540X0**. I used same code that given on android developer page.

```
code added in manifest.xml



<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />

    <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

   <activity
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|
                orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

code in main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:id="@+id/adViewl"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="AD_UNIT_ID" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

and java code

```
      LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)  findViewById(R.id.adViewl);

         AdView adView = new AdView(this);
         adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
         adView.setAdUnitId("AD_UNIT_ID");

        layout.addView(adView);

        //AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build(); // Start
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Please, tell me where i am wrong in above code.

Comment: I had an error when setting in XML and programmmatically ate the same time the AdSize.BANNER. (Error like: AdUnitId can only be set once). Try to remove `adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);`and `adView.setAdUnitId("AD_UNIT_ID");`. Also put `android:layout_height='wrap_content'` on adView and lineareLayout.

Comment: Show the entire main.xml file.

Comment: @William main.xml containing only AdView and LinearLayout code.

Comment: change BANNER to adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);

Comment: btw did u give an Unit Id for ur adView? or its just empty?

Comment: @Umitk Unit id is given.

Comment: did u change and try BANNER type?

Comment: @Umitk yes, changed from Banner to SMART_BANNER, but not showing ad.

Comment: thanks to all. your suggestions helped me to find solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, i got solution to my problem by changing java code. I removed linear layout code from java code. Used only Adview as given below,

```
AdView adView = (AdView) findIdByValue(R.id.adView);
 AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
 adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is "only has 540X0" which means the AdView has no height available.

If the layout given above is the only content of main.xml then you must be using a theme that has somehow reduced the size of the AdView or the LinearLayout to zero.